# Rewrite/Redirect all "someaddress.html" pages to "someaddress/" WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, permalinks

I recently migrated my website - and part of this migration was changing from static html to a wordpress website. All of my links to my site still use the following scheme: `mysite.com/{year}/{month}/somepost.html` whereas my new scheme is `mysite.com/{year}/{month}/somepost/`

How can I redirect (301) using mod_rewrite all URLs with the old pattern to the new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using mod_rewrite you can set your .htaccess file to redirect the incoming links from `http://example.com/2004/04/title_of_post.html` to `http://example.com/2004/04/title-of-post/` by:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/.*)\.html $1/ [R=301,L]
```

There is also a plugin for wordpress, you may have a look [link](https://www.pmg.com/blog/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api/)